# how to get is_abundant with O(sqrtn) without using math library in c

Tags: c

i have a code and im trying to get a O(sqrt(n)) without using math library in c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_abundant(int num);
int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d\n", is_abundant(num));
    return 0;
}
int is_abundant(int num)
{
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    sum = sum - num;
    if (sum > num) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

what can i do to get O(sqrt(n)) ? any help ?

Comment: Hint: same technique as for a naive prime number checker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `num % i == 0` is true, `num % (num / i) == 0` will also be true.

Therefore, you can reduce the loop

```c
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
```

to

```c
    if (num > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i * i <= num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
                if (num / i > i) sum += num / i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that simply changing the condition `i < num` to `i * i <= num`  will allow it to enter the loop when `num = 1`, so I added an `if` statement to deal with this case.

Answer (score 0):

For finding out factors you don't have to run the loop till n times, rather you can just run it till i <= sqrt(n) times or if you don't want to use sqrt lib then simply multiply i two times check if it is less than or equal to num or not.

```
int is_abundant(int num)
{
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i*i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            sum += i;
            sum += num/i; // if all factors you want to add, otherwise ignore
        }
    }
    sum = sum - num;
    if (sum > num) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you define `sqrt`? The condition is "without using math library".

Comment: ya in that case need to multiply i two times

Comment: Also be careful for `num = 1` case. (I found that final result won't change though)

Comment: sum += num/i;  can be added with in if as shown above to include all factors greater than  sqrt(n).